# Loan Program trouble with interface c#

Tags: c#, interface

I seem to be having trouble with interface. I have it where all my calculations work for the loan program, but I can't seem to figure out how to call my interface. I'm sure it's probably something minor that I am overlooking, but for some reason I'm having a blank.

```
Interface:
interface IMyInterface
{
    string iMessage();
}


 public class C1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double interests = 0.0;
        double years = 0.0;
        double loan_amount = 0.0;
        double interest_rate = 0.0;


        Console.Write("Enter Loan Amount:$ ");
        loan_amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Number of Years: ");
        years = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Interest Rate: ");
        interest_rate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        interests = loan_amount * interest_rate * years;
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe total interests is {0}", interests);
        Console.ReadLine();




    }

    public string iMessage()
    {
        return Console.WriteLine("Be Ready!");  
    }
}

class Program
{

}
```

Comment: Well your class doesn't declare that it implements the interface at the moment, and you're never creating an instance of your class, or referring to the interface. Additionally, `Console.WriteLine` is a void method, so you can't use it in a return statement like that...

Comment: Shade, to put it this way, whatever Jon Skeet says, take it as law.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try debugging your code before posting and never have to waste Jon Skeet's time.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok thank-you for pointing that out. I appreciate it.

Comment: when you say `interface` do you mean it in [this sense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) or are you talking about a user interface in a console application? which asks for input and gives output?=!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this help? [See it working here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eeCpI5)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    // Here we instantiate or construct a new instance of ThingWithMessage
    // but we refer to it as thing of type IMyInterface,
    // this works because ThingWithMessage implements IMyInterface.
    // Then we use the interface implementation to get a message and
    // write it to the console.
    public static void Main()
    {
        IMyInterface thing = new ThingWithMessage();
        Console.WriteLine(thing.GetMessage());
    }    
}

// This defines a type, or contract that classes can implement
interface IMyInterface
{
    string GetMessage();
}

// This is a class that implements the IMyInterface interface
// effectively, it makes a promise to keep the contract
// specified by IMyInterface.
class ThingWithMessage : IMyInterface
{
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return "yes, this works.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this fixed it. Thank-you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @Shade, hey, I just about remember what it was like starting out.

Comment: Thank-you for also explaining it out. It made it much easier to understand with your explaination.

Answer (score 0):

This might be something you could use:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    double Calculate();
}

class MyCalculationLogics : IMyInterface
{
    public double Calculate(double loan_amount, double years, double interest_rate)
    {
        return loan_amount * interest_rate * years;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ....
        // Get the values from the user
        ....

        IMyInterface myCalc = new MyCalculationLogics();
        interests = myCalc.Calculate(loan_amount, years, interest_rate);

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe total interests is {0}", interests);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```